# dual boot Ubuntu+Windows 10 problem

Tags: dual-boot

I have a problem with dual boot. If I restart the computer the windows boot manager is not showing in BIOS and in gnu grub. I can only go to ubuntu. How can I backup my Windows? Maybe this information will help you.

```
sudo parted --list 

Model: ATA ST2000LM007-1R81 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 2      274MB   290MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   1973GB  1972GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      1973GB  1999GB  26.8GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      1999GB  2000GB  1049MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag


Model: Intenso Alu Line (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  16.1GB  16.1GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS  

UEFI  

sudo dmidecode -t0 | grep -Ei "BIOS boot|UEFI"  

        BIOS boot specification is supported
        UEFI is supported
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
efibootmgr is already the newest version (15-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (54-E1-AD-AA-EB-FA)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1adaaebfa,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0,0)RC
Boot0001* Linpus lite   HD(1,MBR,0xa401d960,0x800,0x1dff800)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (54-E1-AD-AA-EB-FA)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1adaaebfa,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0005* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,2febd021-19a7-4c9f-95f3-ced547535fbf,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
there is the real codeblock   
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted --list
Model: ATA ST2000LM007-1R81 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                                  Flags
 2      274MB   290MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition     msftres
 3      290MB   1973GB  1972GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      1973GB  1999GB  26.8GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      1999GB  2000GB  1049MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag


Model: Intenso Alu Line (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  16.1GB  16.1GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS 
UEFI
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmidecode -t0 | grep -Ei "BIOS boot|UEFI" 
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        UEFI is supported
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
efibootmgr is already the newest version (15-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (54-E1-AD-AA-EB-FA)         PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1adaaebfa,0)    /IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0,0)RC
Boot0001* Linpus lite   HD(1,MBR,0xa401d960,0x800,0x1dff800)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (54-E1-AD-AA-EB-FA)      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1adaaebfa,0)/IPv6([::]:  <->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0005* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,2febd021-19a7-4c9f-95f3- ced547535fbf,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```